# How to split on linear combination of predictors instead of a predictor for CART model in R

Tags: r

Classification and regression trees by Breiman et al mentioned about using linear combination of predictors when splitting a node. I was trying to find a way to try this out with R in vain.

There are tree or rpart packages which assume splitting on an univariate predictor and they do not allow any customization with linear combination. Do I have to create my own package?

Comment: Do you want the model to decide the linear combination to split on for you or do you just want to be able to split on linear combinations?  If it's the later you could just construct the linear combinations yourself and do CART on those.  I've played with doing CART on PCA scores before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used it before, but you might have a look at the **oblique.tree** [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oblique.tree/index.html) on CRAN.

The example in `?oblique.tree` does in fact add the PCA output at covariates,

```
data(crabs, package = "MASS")
aug.crabs.data <- data.frame(   g=factor(rep(1:4,each=50)),
                predict(princomp(crabs[,4:8]))[,2:3])
```

yielding data that looks like this:

[image]

where the covariates are the 2nd and 3rd principal components. It can then apparently fit a decision tree that splits on linear combinations of these variables:

```
ob.tree <- oblique.tree(formula     = g~.,
            data        = aug.crabs.data,
            oblique.splits  = "only")
plot(ob.tree)
text(ob.tree,cex = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't heard of that but it sounds like it does what Paul wants.